# maxJsonLength is ignored

Tags: json, web-services, serialization, xml-serialization

I am loading an XML file from DB,,when it gets bigger I used maxJsonLength property in my web.config.. but it is totally ignored.. checked online for the issue and done everything possible and its not working.

here is my web.config file

> ```
> <system.web>
>  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
>  <pages theme="Main" styleSheetTheme="Main" />
>  <customErrors mode="Off" />
>  </system.web>
>
> <system.web.extensions>
>  <scripting> 
>  <scriptResourceHandler enableCompression="true" enableCaching="true"/> 
>  <webServices>
>   <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"/>
>  </webServices>
>  </scripting>
> ```

when I load the xml file from DB it gives me an incomplete XML file. normally when I recieve this xml file I split it into a smaller parts and send it to be parced by jquery..so it can handle the large xml data.. but again since the maxJsonLength property has been ignored it is not working..

when I checked it online, some posts said that I have to hard code it,, so I've add a field in my appsettings in my web config file as follows

> ```
> <appSettings>
>    <add key="maxJsonLength " value="5000000" />
> ```

then in my global.asax at the app-start I've added this code:

> ```
> // Code that runs on application startup
>        var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
>        serializer.MaxJsonLength = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[0]);
> ```

again nothing happend...maybe I am putting this code in the wrong place...

I'll appreciate your help.. thanks

// Update

when I used the same call to the DB without JSON,, it gave me the same short xml file,, only returns 2033 charcters,, so I guess this issue might be an SQL issue.. here is my stored procedure for the reference

> ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.LoadMarkers 
>     @CategoryID int = -1,   @MarkerID int= -1 AS
>
> select m.ID as mid,
>
> (case when @MarkerID != -1 then m.MarkerImage end)as mimg,
>
> (case when @MarkerID != -1 then m.Introduction  end)as intr,
>
> (case when @MarkerID != -1 then m.Title  end)as t
>
> ,m.Latitude as lt,m.Longitude as lg,
>
> m.CategoryID as cid,
>
> (case when @MarkerID != -1 then c.Name end),
>
> c.MarkerImage as cimg
>
> ```
>   from Marker m    join Category c on c.ID = m.CategoryID
> ```
>
> where categoryID = (case when @CategoryID != -1 then @CategoryID
>
> ```
>       else categoryID
>
>           end) 
>   and m.ID = (case when @MarkerID != -1 then @MarkerID
>           else m.ID
>           end)
> ```
>
> for XML Path('Marker'),Root('Markers')
>
> RETURN

Comment: Just for the record,,, I think it is not a JSON issue,, because the SQL server returns only 2033 characters.. I am updating the post with my stored procedure as well.

Answer (score 0):

It was not a JSON issue,  it was reading the SQL result using normal execute statement not ExecuteXML..

this issue is now closed.

thanks